# jquery.min.js: 'jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).dialog is not a function' error

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I am trying to get a popup dialog to appear over an image uploader (that's the first div in the body), but I keep getting this error in the jquery.min.js:

jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).dialog is not a function TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function

as well as this error:

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function

The form also does not popup as a separate dialog, but simply appears at the bottom of the screen, as shown below in the link:

https://wardrobed-debjanidas.c9users.io/imageupload

Below is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
              <!---bootstrap stuff--->
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

            <!---my stylesheet--->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />

            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
              crossorigin="anonymous">

            </script>


          <title>Wardrobed</title>


          <style>
            label, input { display:block; }
            input.text { margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em; }
            fieldset { padding:0; border:0; margin-top:25px; }
            h1 { font-size: 1.2em; margin: .6em 0; }
            div#users-contain { width: 350px; margin: 20px 0; }
            div#users-contain table { margin: 1em 0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
            div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th { border: 1px solid #eee; padding: .6em 10px; text-align: left; }
            .ui-dialog .ui-state-error { paddsing: .3em; }
            .validateTips { border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 0.3em; }
          </style>
          <script>
              $( function() {
                var dialog, form,

                  // From http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#e-mail-state-%28type=email%29
                  emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/,
                  name = $( "#name" ),
                  email = $( "#email" ),
                  password = $( "#password" ),
                  allFields = $( [] ).add( name ).add( email ).add( password ),
                  tips = $( ".validateTips" );

                function updateTips( t ) {
                  tips
                    .text( t )
                    .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
                  setTimeout(function() {
                    tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
                  }, 500 );
                }

                function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
                  if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
                    o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
                    updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
                      min + " and " + max + "." );
                    return false;
                  } else {
                    return true;
                  }
                }

                function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
                  if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
                    o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
                    updateTips( n );
                    return false;
                  } else {
                    return true;
                  }
                }

                function addUser() {
                  var valid = true;
                  allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

                  valid = valid && checkLength( name, "username", 3, 16 );
                  valid = valid && checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
                  valid = valid && checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );

                  valid = valid && checkRegexp( name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, spaces and must begin with a letter." );
                  valid = valid && checkRegexp( email, emailRegex, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
                  valid = valid && checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );

                  if ( valid ) {
                    $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
                      "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
                      "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" +
                      "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>" );
                    dialog.dialog( "close" );
                  }
                  return valid;
                }

                dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
                  autoOpen: false,
                  height: 400,
                  width: 350,
                  modal: true,
                  buttons: {
                    "Create an account": addUser,
                      Cancel: function() {
                      dialog.dialog( "close" );
                    }
                  },
                  close: function() {
                    form[ 0 ].reset();
                    allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
                  }
                });

                form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
                  event.preventDefault();
                   addUser();
                });

                $( "#create-user" ).button().on( "click", function() {
                  dialog.dialog( "open" );
                });
              } );
          </script>
        </head>
        <body>

          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span>
                    <h2>Item Uploader</h2>
                    <h4>Wardrobed</h4>
                    <div class="progress">
                      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-lg upload-btn" type="button">Upload Image</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <input id="upload-input" type="file" name="uploads[]" multiple="multiple"></br>
          <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
            <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

            <form>
              <fieldset>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Jane Smith" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="jane@smith.com" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="xxxxxxx" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">

                <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
                <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
              </fieldset>
            </form>
          </div>


          <div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
            <h1>Existing Users:</h1>
            <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
              <thead>
                <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Password</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>John Doe</td>
                  <td>john.doe@example.com</td>
                  <td>johndoe1</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <button id="create-user">Create new user</button>

          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <script src="javascripts/upload.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I've tried updating my bootstrap cdn to 4.0.0, but that causes the image uploader div to disappear and the form stays at the bottom of the page. Does anyone know how I should fix this?

Comment: You're including multiple versions of jQuery. You need to use only one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First load "jquery-2.2.0.min.js" then "jquery-ui.min.js" to remove the error.